# Term/theory of psychological effect: asking for counter-arguments without (ever thinking of) considering them in decision

Tags: terminology

Is there a known psychological effect or theorie that describes and explains this phenomenon:
Someone facing a (buying)decision asks another person about the cons of buying, but instead of evaluating the list of cons deeply, in an affirmative manner the list psychologically just serves to corroborate the decision to buy (*"Glad you mentioned that, but …"*). As the person being asked, you got a strong feeling that the decision was already made before asking the cons and you serve as a kind of dummy.

Comment: See the meta post here: https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2374/not-all-observations-necessarily-need-a-term-in-psychology For the situation you describe, though, I do the behavior you describe all the time, but it's not that I'm *not considering* the counter-arguments. If I see an item with good reviews, I'll still check the "one-star" reviews to see what they complain about. If they complain about something I care about, I consider them; if the one-star reviews refer to things I'm not worried about then I ignore them.

Comment: In summary, I think you need to show some stronger evidence that the thing you are describing is a true phenomenon, because I think there are other simpler explanations like the one I just gave.

Comment: For more duplicates, see list in: [Denial of evidence and reason](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/13173/7001)